# How do I define a virtual function whose parameters differ in descendant classes?

Tags: delphi, polymorphism

I wanted to have a
Copy routine that is defined virtual in base class and implemented in derived class later.
The problem is that it is not allowed to override the procedure due to different parameter.
Is there any solution with Delphi's class model or is my approach completely wrong?

```
type
  TCar = class
    procedure CopyFrom(c: TCar); virtual;
  end;

  TChrysler = class(TCar)
    FColor: Integer;
    procedure CopyFrom(c: TChrysler); override;
  end;

procedure TCar.CopyFrom(c: TCar);
begin
  //virtual
end;

procedure TChrysler.CopyFrom(c: TCrysler);
begin
  FColor := c.FColor;
end;

var
  Car1, Car2: TCar;
begin
  Car1 := TChrysler.Create;
  Car2 := TChrysler.Create;

  Car2.CopyFrom(Car1); //TChrysler.CopyFrom should be called.
end;
```

Comment: You're looking for [`reintroduce`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Methods#Reintroduce).

Comment: Looks like TPersistent.Assign, which I hate as it happens.

Comment: The typical approach in Delphi is to provide `Assign` and `AssignTo` methods, that you would use as `Car2.Assign(Car1);`. If you look at the VCL source code, you can see many examples of using this technique that work correctly with derived classes that have new properties. See, for instance, `TStringList.Assign` in the `Classes` unit.

Comment: The Assign method came also into my mind some minutes before. Possible. But it could be also a EqualTo procedure or something else. Not restricted to CopyFrom/Assign.

Comment: @TLama: reintroduce does not work together with override. It's needed.

Comment: You'd use `reintroduce` instead of `override`.

Comment: In languages that allow descendants' methods' parameter types to be different, you'll find that the types must be *contravariant* with respect to the class type. You're hoping for *covariant* types, though, which is fundamentally unsound. It's the *return* type that can be covariant (in languages that allow variance; Delphi isn't included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep the parameter list the same, just do a type-check inside of the implementation:

```
type
  TCar = class
    procedure CopyFrom(c: TCar); virtual;
  end;

  TChrysler = class(TCar)
    FColor: Integer;
    procedure CopyFrom(c: TCar); override;
  end;

procedure TCar.CopyFrom(c: TCar);
begin
  //virtual
end;

procedure TChrysler.CopyFrom(c: TCar);
begin
  if c is TCrysler then
    FColor := TCrysler(c).FColor;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: @user2217747: It's hardly a new idea, actually.  Look at `TPersistent.Assign`, which works the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately without type safety during compile time. Thanks to all for the replies!

Comment: If you want type safety you don't want polymorphism which is by definition a relaxation of static type rules. What benefit does combining inheritance with type checks that block further inheritance do?